# 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'String'

Tags: ios, string, swift

```
var sectionTitles: [String] = ["Apple", "Brownie", "Cupcakes"]

var sectionIndexTitles: [String]{
    get{

        return sectionTitles.map { $0.substringToIndex(2) }

    }
}
```

I get compiler error on `sectionIndexTitles`, that `'NSString' is not a subtype of 'String'`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `substringToIndex()` method exists for both `NSString` and `String`, but
the two methods have different parameter types.

The `NSString` method
takes an `Int`, so you can cast `$0` to `NSString` as shown in
Roman Salabay's answer.

The `String` method takes an `String.Index` parameter, which looks
a bit complicated:

```
var sectionIndexTitles: [String] {
    get {
        return sectionTitles.map {
            $0.substringToIndex(advance($0.startIndex, 2, $0.endIndex))
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a generic

```
func prefix<S : Sliceable>(s: S, maxLength: Int) -> S.SubSlice
```

method which can be used here:

```
var sectionIndexTitles: [String] {
    get {
        return sectionTitles.map {
            prefix($0, 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change 2 in second example to 3, so it'll be clear that it's length of substring.

Comment: @Shmidt: Sorry, I don't get it. `prefix($0, 2)` returns a substring of length 2 (or less if the string is shorter).

Comment: substringToIndex(2) return length 3, isn't it?

Comment: @Shmidt: No. substringToIndex  returns a new string containing the characters of the receiver up to, **but not including**, the one at a given index. substringToIndex(2) returns a string of length 2.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast String to NSString. See code below:

```
var sectionIndexTitles: [String]{
        get{
            return sectionTitles.map {
                ($0 as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**
And because you are not using setter you can simplify this code by omitting getter declaration like this:

```
var sectionIndexTitles: [String] {
        return sectionTitles.map { ($0 as NSString).substringToIndex(2) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here without passing through `NSString` conversion:

```
let sectionTitles = ["hello", "world"]
let xs = sectionTitles.map { $0.substringToIndex(advance($0.startIndex, 2))}
xs // ["he", "wo"]
```

Problem is that `String` has its own `Index` type. This mainly due to the various `UTF` representations it handles. AFAIK `NSString` mainly uses `UTF-8` internal representations.

Comment: Note that `advance($0.startIndex, 2)` crashes if the string has only one character.

Comment: Keep in mind that both `NSString` and `String` will in case of a string shorter than 2. The `NSString` `length` will return the `UTF-8` representation count. To count `String` use `countElements` for Swift 1.1, or simply `count` for Swift 1.2